# Which is the default bar tint color in iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uikit, ios7, uitoolbar

I would like to set the background (bar tint color) of a toolbar in iOS 7 to the default color (white, light gray) as shown in the screen shot below.

I tried both color variants, but none matches the default color which looks like this:

[image]

Which would be the correct color to specify here?

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = // ????
```

Comment: Have you tried doing nothing?

Comment: Anyway the color feels different with different content under the tool bar.

Comment: @Moxy I have tried `clearColor`, `white` and `lightGray`. None of these colors matches the default color. "Doing nothing" resulted in a dark brownish color tone.

Comment: The default bar "color" in iOS 7 is transparency with a blur. So, are you really asking how to revert back to the iOS 6 bar color? Have you tried toggling the transparency?

Comment: @bilobatum Toggling the transparency did not help. I do want to show a iOS 7 default bar color. For some strange reason my bar is shown in a different color.

Comment: I've got the same question, but for the `UINavigationBar` instead. It seems like it's white but it's got a tinge of brown. Wonder what color that is.

Comment: It seems close to `[UIColor colorWithWhite:(CGFloat)(247.0/255) alpha:(CGFloat)(240.0/255)]` though the default one has a mild gradient that gets darker by a couple of points starting from half the height until the bottom of the navigation bar.

Comment: I found it using Reveal app which still doesn't directly provide this property but by digging into the exact view that has this color. They say the property will be explicitly added soon at http://support.revealapp.com/discussions/suggestions/1025-uinavigationbar-bartintcolor

Comment: Weird thing is, the documentation says the default is `[UIColor whiteColor]`! "Tint Color: You can specify a custom tint color for the navigation bar background using the Tint (`barTintColor`) field. The default background tint color is white." Link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UINavigationBar-SW3

Answer (score 4):

use this:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.barTintColor = nil;
self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

you can add default color to all UIToolbar using

```
UIToolbar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.lightGray
```